# Difference b/w these two ways of clearing contents using named range

Tags: vba

What's the difference between the below two ways of clearing contents using named ranges? I noticed that method B clears ***everything*** past the named range, while method A only clears contents ***within*** the named range. Why is that?

***A***

```
lastRow = Range("sTable").Rows.Count
With Range("sTable")
    .Range("A1:S" & lastRow).ClearContents
End With
```

vs

***B***

```
lastRow = Range("sTable").Rows.Count
lastCol = range("sTable").columns.count
With Range("sTable")
    .Range(.cells(1,1),.cells(lastRow,lastcol)).ClearContents
End With
```

Comment: the two methods clear **_within_** the named ranges.

Comment: Isn't the same of doing Range("sTable").ClearContents? Why counting rows before clearing if you are clearing everything.

Comment: @exSnake, the OP is not aware of what range is being referenced. if they were, the question would have never been posted